# QDateTimeEdit shows wrong timezone

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyside2

I'm trying to use a QDateTimeEdit widget in Python3 / PySide / QT5 but with a different timezone than the local time. Switching between local and UTC works but I can't get QDateTimeEdit to show a different timezone:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import datetime
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dte = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
    timezone = QtCore.QTimeZone(b'Asia/Dubai')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("datetime local = {0}".format(now))
    now = QtCore.QDateTime(now)
    print("QDateTime local = {0}".format(now))
    now = now.toTimeZone(timezone)
    print("QDateTime Dubai = {0}".format(now))
    print("  time zone = {0}".format(now.timeZone()))
    print("  time spec = {0}".format(now.timeSpec()))
    print("  formated  = {0}".format(now.toString("dddd, MMMM d. yyyy hh:mm t")))
    dte.setDisplayFormat("dddd, MMMM d. yyyy hh:mm t")
    dte.setTimeSpec(QtCore.Qt.TimeZone)
    dte.setDateTime(now)
    dte.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running this shows me the expected output on the console but then shows the time in Dubai but with *CEST* as time zone in the QDateTimeEdit:

```
datetime local = 2023-08-23 10:51:40.678874
QDateTime local = PySide2.QtCore.QDateTime(2023, 8, 23, 10, 51, 40, 678, 0)
QDateTime Dubai = PySide2.QtCore.QDateTime(2023, 8, 23, 12, 51, 40, 678, 3)  
  time zone = <PySide2.QtCore.QTimeZone("Asia/Dubai") at 0x7fd415ccb300>
  time spec = PySide2.QtCore.Qt.TimeSpec.TimeZone
  formated  =  Wednesday, August 23. 2023 12:51 +04
```

Note: The QDateTime widget shows "Wednesday, August 23, 2023 12:51 *CEST*". Right time, wrong timezone. Which is just totally wrong.

So what am I missing to get it to show "+04" as time zone in the QDateEdit?

PS: Can anyone try this quickly in C++? Is this a PySide2 bug?

PPS: If you happen to live in the Dubai timezone change the example to somewhere else.

Comment: This kind of issues don't relate to PySide/PyQt since there's no Python object conversion in between that could cause inconsistency. It's probably related to [QTBUG-80417](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80417), which is still unfixed even in Qt6. In the meantime, you could consider working around it by subclassing and overriding `textFromDateTime()` and `dateTimeFromText()`, possibly by considering the QDateTime spec into account when using `setDateTime()`.